# Pygame- How to shoot in direction of player sprite?

Tags: python, rotation, pygame

I'm making an Asteroids clone, and I'm having trouble figuring out where to store the angle of the player sprite's movement and how to have the bullet access that (if that makes any sense). Right now, I think my ship's rotation is stored in the angle_speed variable, which I'm using to produce the bullet's dest_x and dest_y (destination x and y) coordinates. However the bullet keeps shooting to (0, 0). Can anybody help?

```
try:
    import sys
    import math
    import os
    import getopt
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    from pygame.math import Vector2
except ImportError, err:
    print "couldn't load module. %s" % (err)
    sys.exit(2)

# these are warnings if font or sound modules are not available.
if not pygame.font: print 'Warning, fonts disabled'
if not pygame.mixer: print 'Warning, sound disabled'

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """moves ship on screen"""
    def __init__(self, pos=(420,420)):
        super(Player, self).__init__() # call Sprite initializer
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.original_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.position = Vector2(pos)
        self.direction = Vector2(0,1)
        self.speed = 0
        self.angle_speed = 0
        self.angle = 0


    def update(self):
        if self.angle_speed != 0:
            # Rotate the direction vector and then the image
            self.direction.rotate_ip(self.angle_speed)
            self.angle += self.angle_speed
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, -self.angle)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop=self.rect.midtop)
        # Update the position vector and the rect.
        self.position += self.direction * self.speed
        self.rect.center = self.position
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bullet. """

    def __init__(self, start_x, start_y, dest_x, dest_y):
        """ Constructor.
        It takes in the starting x and y location.
        It also takes in the destination x and y position.
        """

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()

        # Set up the image for the bullet
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Move the bullet to our starting location
        self.rect.x = start_x
        self.rect.y = start_y

        # Because rect.x and rect.y are automatically converted
        # to integers, we need to create different variables that
        # store the location as floating point numbers. Integers
        # are not accurate enough for aiming.
        self.floating_point_x = start_x
        self.floating_point_y = start_y

        # Calculation the angle in radians between the start points
        # and end points. This is the angle the bullet will travel.
        x_diff = dest_x - start_x
        y_diff = dest_y - start_y
        angle = math.atan2(y_diff, x_diff);

        # Taking into account the angle, calculate our change_x
        # and change_y. Velocity is how fast the bullet travels.
        velocity = 11
        self.change_x = math.cos(angle) * velocity
        self.change_y = math.sin(angle) * velocity

    def update(self):
        """ Move the bullet. """

        # The floating point x and y hold our more accurate location.
        self.floating_point_y += self.change_y
        self.floating_point_x += self.change_x

        # The rect.x and rect.y are converted to integers.
        self.rect.y = int(self.floating_point_y)
        self.rect.x = int(self.floating_point_x)

        # If the bullet flies of the screen, get rid of it.
        if self.rect.x < 0 or self.rect.x > SCREEN_WIDTH or self.rect.y < 0 or self.rect.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.kill()

def main():


    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(500,30)


    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
    pygame.display.set_caption('Asteroids')

    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    # List of each bullet
    bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullets = []

    player = Player()
    all_sprites_list.add(player)

    MAXSPEED = 15
    MINSPEED = -5

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    done = False
    while not done:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP and player.speed > MINSPEED:
                    player.speed -= 3
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and player.speed < MAXSPEED:
                    player.speed += 3
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.angle_speed = -3
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.angle_speed = 3
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                    dest_x = math.sin(player.angle_speed)
                    dest_y = math.cos(player.angle_speed)
                    # Create the bullet based on where we are, and where we want to go.
                    bullet = Bullet(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, dest_x, dest_y)

                    # Add the bullet to the lists
                    all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                    bullet_list.add(bullet)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.angle_speed = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.angle_speed = 0

        all_sprites_list.update()
        player.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        # screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle is stored in the `self.angle` attribute of the `player` sprite. The `angle_speed` is just the speed by which it rotates.

There's no need to calculate the angle and velocity of the bullets, since you can just pass the `angle` and `direction` of the player sprite.

```
import math
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2


SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos=(420, 420)):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 40], pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.original_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.position = Vector2(pos)
        # The vector points upwards.
        self.direction = Vector2(0, -1)
        self.speed = 0
        self.angle_speed = 0
        self.angle = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.angle_speed != 0:
            # Rotate the direction vector and then the image
            self.direction.rotate_ip(self.angle_speed)
            self.angle += self.angle_speed
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, -self.angle)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop=self.rect.midtop)
        # Update the position vector and the rect.
        self.position += self.direction * self.speed
        self.rect.center = self.position


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bullet. """

    def __init__(self, pos, direction, angle):
        """Take the pos, direction and angle of the player."""
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10], pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        # Rotate the image by the player.angle (negative since y-axis is flipped).
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, -angle, 1)
        # Pass the center of the player as the center of the bullet.rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.position = Vector2(pos)  # The position vector.
        self.velocity = direction * 11  # Multiply by desired speed.

    def update(self):
        """Move the bullet."""
        self.position += self.velocity  # Update the position vector.
        self.rect.center = self.position  # And the rect.

        if self.rect.x < 0 or self.rect.x > SCREEN_WIDTH or self.rect.y < 0 or self.rect.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.kill()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(500,30)

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()  # "group" not "list".

    player = Player()
    all_sprites_list.add(player)

    MAXSPEED = 15
    MINSPEED = -5

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    done = False
    while not done:
        clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP and player.speed > MINSPEED:
                    player.speed += 3
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and player.speed < MAXSPEED:
                    player.speed -= 3
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.angle_speed = -3
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.angle_speed = 3
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    # Just pass the rect.center, direction vector and angle.
                    bullet = Bullet(
                        player.rect.center, player.direction, player.angle)
                    all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                    bullet_group.add(bullet)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.angle_speed = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.angle_speed = 0

        all_sprites_list.update()
        player.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

        screen.fill(WHITE)
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```